# Are Oreos vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

There are many contradictory sources on whether the classic black Oreo "Sandwich Cookies" are vegan or not.

Though sold almost worldwide, classic Oreos are produced in just a handful of big factories around the world by Mondelez/Nabisco/Cadbury/Milka.

**Are all classic Oreos vegan?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It depends.

The classic Oreo cookie is made using the same [main ingredients](https://nutritionbeast.com/2013/10/oreo-cookie-ingredients-nutrition-history/), With some substitutions like in Canada, where the vegetable oil is coconut oil. **None of these ingredients are currently of animal origin:**

- Sugar
- Unbleached enriched flour (wheat flour, niacin, iron, thiamine mono-nitrate (vitamin B1), riboflavin (vitamin B2), folic acid)
- High oleic canola oil and/or palm oil and/or canola oil
- Cocoa (treated with alkali)
- High-fructose corn syrup
- Leavening agent (baking soda and/or monocalcium phosphate)
- Corn starch
- Salt
- Soy lecithin
- Vanillin
- Chocolate
- Palm oil

The contradictions seem to stem from the fact that the manufacturers themselves state that they are not vegan. According to the [official UK site FAQ](https://www.oreo.co.uk/faq) (emphasis mine):

> No, Oreo have milk as **cross contact** and therefore they are not suitable for vegans.

However, some vegans including myself, and although I would rather buy products from brands that are entirely cruelty-free, would not deem them non-vegan solely because of cross-contamination risk.

This was different in the past as milk whey was used as an ingredient for the filling in the EU market.

The bottom line is:

Ingredients of this heavily processed, industrialized snacks **change often** as they are always trying to reduce costs. Try to stay away from this gamble and if there isn't a choice, carefully read the ingredients on **that particular package**. Of course, also decide for yourself whether "might contain traces of milk" is acceptable.

Comment: I think you should add the ingredient list in your post in case the site you linked become unavailable.

Answer (score -3):

Oreo is vegan or not this is kind of a never-ending debate but after PETA post that It's true, #Oreos are #vegan! Did you know all these other snacks are too? this tweet we can say [Oreo are vegan friendly](https://www.wat-not.com/are-oreos-vegan-can-vegans-eat-oreo-cookies/).

Comment: This is beyond incoherent and links to a site with pop-up window covering pop-up window. Voting to delete.